# use field in index name for elasticsearch plugin logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to have elasticsearch index based on field so I can get an index for each source (allowing for secure access to each index).

I tried something along the lines of

```
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch {
       index => [SERVER]"-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

as well as

```
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch{
       index => "[SERVER]-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}
```

and neither work : first errors, second tries to create the index with [SERVER] in it then errors due to uppercase, this might not be supported as I can't find it anywhere in the docs, but I was wondering if anyone has gotten something like this functional for their own ELK stacks?

Answer (score 3):

The right syntax for this is `"%{SERVER}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"`

According [to the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-index) :

> [The index to write] can be dynamic using the %{foo} syntax.

Comment: how did i miss that... smh

Comment: i tried output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    elasticsearch{
       index => "%{SERVER}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    }
}

Comment: the above still didnt work, are you sure it can be mapped to fields?

Comment: Well it worked in my case... Could you give more information => What happened this time (errors, index created with the wrong name...)? And maybe your configuration?

Comment: that is the exact output configuration, in my filter i extract a field named SERVER using grok, it is simply sending the entire string %{SERVER} where it should be replacing the variable causing ES to reject it ( the field definitely exists i can see it in the output when i am using an index name that works)

Comment: Maybe your index name is invalid (for example dots are forbidden in index names)